# Can't connect to Liquidsoap using telnet from remote machine

Tags: telnet, liquidsoap

According to the liquidsoap documentation, I should be able to set up a telnet server like this:

```
set("server.telnet",true)
set("server.telnet.port", 1201)
```

Unfortunately, while I'm able to connect to this from `localhost`, I can't connect to it from a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set("server.telnet",true)
set("server.telnet.port",1201)
set("server.telnet.bind_addr","0.0.0.0")
```

0.0.0.0 for all network interfaces, 127.0.0.1 for localhost-only